# How to run ROS code using Service File

Tags: ros, service

I have two service files that are running ros code . When I start my system the service file B  complains about not able to look for the robot model, then when I stop both service files and start manual using command roslaunch project-name launch file, and then starts service B it works , after that I close the manual roslaunch command using control c and start service file A and now when I restart service file B it works .

```
[Unit]
Description=ROS Launch Service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/home/orangepi/one/killall_roscore_check.sh 
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStart=/home/orangepi/one/requried-files/run2.sh
Restart=always
User=orangepi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**killall_roscore_check.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -x "roscore" > /dev/null; then
    echo "ROS is running. Restarting with rosmaster kill..."
    killall -9 rosmaster
else
    echo "ROS is not running. Skipping rosmaster kill."
fi
```

**run2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source necessary setup files
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
source /home/orangepi/one/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

# Launch the ROS launch file and pipe its output to a while loop
roslaunch /home/orangepi/one/catkin_ws/src/project1/launch/run2_robot.launch





[Unit]
Description=ROS Launch Service
After=one.service

[Service]
#ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash && source /home/orangepi/one/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash && roslaunch /home/orangepi/one/catkin_ws/src/abc/project/launch/run.launch"
Restart=always
User=orangepi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay , I resolved this problem by providing service 2 20 seconds when restarting the computer using,

```
#ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20
```

By doing this I made sure that that that service file 1 is has provided everything on the parameter service and has launched all required file successfully.